# CLICK JAVAFXML BUTTON SCENEBUILDER

Tags: button, click, fxml

```
@FXML
void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    buttonOpenFile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                openFiletxtField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }

        }
    });

    buttonSaveFile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            File file = new File("Details.txt");
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                osw.write("whatever you need to write");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Successfully..");
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException iOException) {
                System.out.println("" + iOException.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });

}
```

I Have a problem using javafx fxml button click event. Whenever I click the button once, nothing happens. I have to click it the second time for it to work? What could I be doing wrong? I have shared my code above. I am using scene builder I have everything in place apart from this error. everything is working fine apart from this issue. The code load text file from the computer directory and save the data to the loaded file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
void handleOpenFileButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        openFiletxtField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}

@FXML
void handleSaveFileButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    File file = new File("Details.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(firstNametxtField.getText() + "," + lastNametxtField1.getText() + "," + enrolledCheckBox.isSelected() + "," + addresstxtField.getText() + "," + statesCombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Successfully..");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.out.println("" + iOException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).